# Why am I not able to stream the following (BBC Radio 2) link in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am able to stream from the VLCPlayer, but I am trying to figure out what am I doing wrong in my Android App, or does the MediaPlayer supports this type of link stream at all.

http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_intl_lc_radio2_q?s=1380803575&e=1380817975&h=422d6c4a183efc103e3984d4394efd11

This is how I initialize and setup my MediaPlayer object:

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioLink);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

In the OnPrepared callback I am starting the player and in the onError I am printing the error code which is 100:

```
    public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED
```

Added in API level 1
Media server died. In this case, the application must release the MediaPlayer object and instantiate a new one.

In my basic Android project I am able to play other links extracted from different radios (pls, m3u ..), but I am particularly curious what it is that stops me from playing the BBC stream inside my Android app.

Here is link to the .pls file with stream links inside of it:
http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r2_aaclca.pls

I would really appreciate if someone takes the time to observe my problem and share their experience. Thank you